# Order of execution of system call in xv6

Tags: unix, operating-system, system-calls, xv6

When we use the system call (at the user level), we never put the **sys_** prefix, but why when we call the system call function, first the system call handler function (which is prefixed with **sys_** )is called.Here we called the sleep function, but it enters the **sys_sleep()** function and then enters the main **sleep()** function. : for example in ***user level program*** :

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{  
    sleep(2);
    return 0
}
```

Here we called the sleep function, but it enters the **sys_sleep()** function and then enters the main sleep function. :

```
int
sys_sleep(void)
{
  int n;
  uint ticks0;

  if(argint(0, &n) < 0)
    return -1;
  acquire(&tickslock);
  ticks0 = ticks;
  while(ticks - ticks0 < n){
    if(myproc()->killed){
      release(&tickslock);
      return -1;
    }
    sleep(&ticks, &tickslock); //Here the main sleep() function is called.
  }
  release(&tickslock);
  return 0;
}
```

How does this happen? We didn't write call **sys_sleep()** in the ***user level program***, but it entered there first, then the main **sleep()** function was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sleep() function is a standard UNIX function normally found in unistd.h. Most functions in the standard library are implemented by providing a shared library that is linked to your executable. The functions in this shared library will use system calls to ask the OS kernel to provide services related to the function you called.

The name of the function itself is often masked with macros. In the header that you include, the macro is defined like

```
#define sleep sys_sleep
```

You are calling sleep from your code but the compiler replaces every occurence of sleep with sys_sleep. The shared library itself isn't the system call. The shared library is a wrapper to simplify making system calls and modularize the compiler. The compiler doesn't meddle with syscalls as long as you don't call in that shared library and link it with your code. When you do this, the shared library contains code such as

```
mov rax, SYSCALL_NUMBER
syscall
```

The first instruction puts the syscall number in a register and [syscall](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/syscall) is executed which makes the processor jump at the syscall handler setup by the OS at boot. The handler looks at rax and switches on the value to determine what syscall it is handling. To help you understand, I made a small **Linux example**:

Create the 3 following files:

main.c

```
#include "shared.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    print("hello\n");
}
```

shared.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "shared.h"

void sys_print(char* str){
    printf(str);
}
```

shared.h

```
#ifndef SHARED
#define SHARED
#define print sys_print

void sys_print(char* str);

#endif
```

Now run the following:

```
gcc -g -fPIC -shared -o libshared.so shared.c
gcc -g main.c -omain -I. -L. -lshared
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
gdb -ex start --args ./main
```

You should see something like:

```
Reading symbols from ./main...
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x115c: file main.c, line 4.
Starting program: /home/user/main 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe0f8) at main.c:4
4       print("hello\n");
(gdb)
```

Now you can type `layout asm` and press enter to see the assembly while you step in it. Type `si` then press enter repeatedly to single step instructions. You'll see that you get similar results than with your sleep() syscall. This is exactly what is done with the standard library implementation except that the shared library will be linked with small assembly snippets such as the ones containing the instruction `syscall`.

Answer (score 1):

`sleep` is **declared** in [user.h](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/user.h).

`sleep` is **defined** in [usys.S](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/usys.S):

Lets see:

```
SYSCALL(sleep)
```

Will be transformed in

```
  .globl sleep; 
  sleep: 
    movl $SYS_ ## sleep, %eax; 
    int $T_SYSCALL; 
    ret
```

What happened?

When (user) function `sleep` is called

- register `%eax` is set to `SYS_sleep` (which value is 13 (see [syscall.h](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/syscall.h)) and `SYS_sleep` is defined in [sysproc.c](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/sysproc.c)
- interuption `T_SYSCALL` (64 see [traps.h](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/traps.h))  is raised.
- after the system call returned, `sleep` returns too.

---

The `sleep` definition called by `sys_sleep` and that is only accessible from kernel mode is in [proc.c](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/proc.c)